# Multi-variable continuity piecewise problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

I've worked on this for about 3 hours and I can't seem to get anywhere with it. I tried using java code to return the solution but one that met the criteria was not found.

Find the value of $c$ and $d$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous:

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&2x^2 + cx + d &&: x < -3\\
&-1 &&: x = -3\\
&dx^2+5x+c &&: x>-3
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Comment: This does touches calculus but very vaguely, is the first time I see the *calculus* and *algebra-precalculus* tags together...

Answer (score 2):

If our function is continuous, each piece ought to agree at $x=-3$:$$2(-3)^2+c(-3)+d=-1=d(-3)^2+5(-3)+c\\18-3c+d=-1=9d-15+c$$so $$3(9d-15+c)=3(-1)\\27d-45+3c=-3$$which gives$$18-3c+d+27d-45+3c=-1-3\\-27+28d=-4\\d=\frac{23}{28}$$and ultimately$$18-3c+\frac{23}{28}=-1\\-3c=-19-\frac{23}{28}\\c=\frac{185}{28}$$